# In Postgresql, Sequence numbers set to start at 1, but is actually returning new records with id of 2?

Tags: postgresql, sequence-sql

Using `setval('sequence',1)` sets the start value of the sequence to 1. But when a record is inserted, the first 'sequence' number is actually 2.

How do I get the actual first record to have a sequence number of 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

> `setval`
>   Reset the sequence object's counter value. The two-parameter form sets the sequence's `last_value` field to the specified value and sets its `is_called` field to true, meaning that the next `nextval` will advance the sequence before returning a value. [...]
>
> ```
> SELECT setval('foo', 42);           Next nextval will return 43
> SELECT setval('foo', 42, true);     Same as above
> SELECT setval('foo', 42, false);    Next nextval will return 42
> ```

So calling `setval('sequence', 1)` sets the sequence's current value to `1` and the *next* value will be `2`. You probably want the three argument form of `setval`:

```
setval('sequence', 1, false)
```

so that the `is_called` flag on the sequence will be false and `nextval('sequence')` will be `1`. Also note that the default value for columns bound to sequences is `nextval('sequence')`.